# Docker-Compose up -d fails with unhealthy xconnect and cm

Tags: docker, container

I'm having trouble getting a basic xp0 environment set up on my local development machine. When I run `docker-compose up` it times out on the xconnect healthcheck because of a SQL login error to the `Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager` database. When I connect to the SQL server with SQL Server Management Studio from my host (localhost,14433), I see that that database is not installed (its mdf/ldf files are not in the `mssql-data` folder, either).

Any ideas why that database wouldn't be included?

### Error messages

```
Creating network "sitecore-xp0_default" with the default driver
Creating sitecore-xp0_mssql_1 ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_solr_1  ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1 ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_id_1       ... done
Creating sitecore-xp0_cm_1       ... done
ERROR: for xdbsearchworker  Container "2cecc38acde2" is unhealthy.
ERROR: for xdbautomationworker  Container "2cecc38acde2" is unhealthy.
ERROR: for cortexprocessingworker  Container "2cecc38acde2" is unhealthy.
ERROR: for traefik  Container "692fab8efdaa" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

### Things I've tried

1. Cleaning and retrying (`docker-compose down; .\clean.ps1; docker-compose up -d`)
2. Completely redownloading all images (`docker-compose down; .\clean.ps1; docker image prune -a; docker-compose up -d`)

#### Environment details

- I'm using the `ltsc-2019` **getting-started** examples from the [Docker Examples Sitecore repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples)
- I'm using the defaults for everything in the `.env` file and `init.ps1`

Comment: How exactly did you give the NETWORK SERVICE account access to the mssql-data folder on my host ?

Comment: You can do it the standard way: right-click on the folder, select properties, click on the Security tab, click Add, and type in `NETWORK SERVICE` and hit enter, then set the permissions to at least Read and Write (Full Control also works).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick fix

This turned out to be a permissions issue that prevented the `ShardMapManager` database (and accompanying shard databases) from being installed. To fix it, I needed to give the `NETWORK SERVICE` account access to the `mssql-data` folder on my host.

### More info on troubleshooting

Run `docker-compose logs mssql` to see the logs for the SQL server. In my case, it showed the following error:

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\data\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager.mdf'.

Since it was trying to create the database in a volume mapped to the host (and volume permissions are shared between host and container), I discovered I needed to adjust the permissions of that directory. I ran the following commands to see what account I needed to grant access to:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> powershell
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | ft -auto
```

[image]

These commands showed me that the `sqlserver` process was running as **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE**, which did not have access to the `mssql-data` folder. Granting access resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue too during installation. Try the below steps:

1. Run `docker-compose stop` on Powershell.
2. Run `docker-compose down` on Powershell.
3. Now run `iisreset /stop` on Powershell to make sure that the required ports are free.
4. Now run `docker-compose up -d` on Powershell.

Hoping this solves your issue.

Comment: Hi Vinay, this worked for me after not knowing how I ended up breaking stuff.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you Chris.

Comment: This worked for me, thought it was a port issue as VS was also not connecting to TFS when docker was running

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answer: It is worth noting that running a clean on the host directory can help, especially after granting NETWORK SERVICE full access to the MSSQL directory as the databases will need to re-established at run time.

The clean.ps1 can be found here:
https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/blob/develop/getting-started/clean.ps1

Apologise for not adding this as a comment - I don't have enough reputational points to add comments apparently.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible root cause:** In default `init.ps1` in `docker-example` repository, `SqlSaPassword`  does not meets SQL complexity requirements.

**Troubleshoot**

First of all, check the logs by running this command:

```
Docker logs <container-id>
```

Eg. docker logs 2cecc38acde2

Alternatively, you can run this command as well: `docker-compose logs mssql`

You might see this error in logs:

```
Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.ShardManagementException: Store Error: Cannot open database "Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.. The error occurred while attempting to perform the underlying storage operation during 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.StoreException: Error occurred while performing store operation. 

See the inner SqlException for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'. 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
```

This error means the SQL password is not correctly set. Open the `init.ps1` file and give a strong SQL admin password. I've used this script to generate the SQL password and save the init.ps1 file.

```
# SQL_SA_PASSWORD
# Need to ensure it meets SQL complexity requirements
Set-EnvFileVariable "SQL_SA_PASSWORD" -Value (Get-SitecoreRandomString 19 -DisallowSpecial -EnforceComplexity)
```

Run `docker-compose down` and then cd to docker folder and run `.\clean.ps1`

Now, run the `.\init.ps1 -LicenseXmlPath C:\License\license.xml`
This script will set the strong password SQL SA password in `.env` file.

And then, `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 1):

We ran the `getting-started` docker scripts and everything seemed to go well, but when starting the containers that were the message we got also.

Our issue ended up being resolved by `stopping IIS` on our machine. We had existing bindings to `443` and that probably was causing a number of issues with our `Sitecore docker containers`. However, the only error that would appear during `docker-compose` up was `xconnect is unhealthy`.

Answer (score -1):

I  also faced this issue during installation. So I tried this.

Run **docker-compose up -d**  in powershell for 2 3 times and it works.

Comment: Run it a few times is not a solution

Comment: It can be in some cases. Just not this one.